# Enable fingerprint service again after successful authentication

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I have implemented login using finger print authentication and it works well.

Below is the Activity that calls the authenticate method:

**FingerPrintActivity**

```
onCreate(){
  … //Code to initialize the fingerprint manager

  FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler = new FingerprintHandler(this);
  fingerprintHandler.startAuthentication(fingerprintManagerCompat, null);
}
```

**FingerPrintHandler**

```
 @Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
    updateLoginUi("Successfully verified!", true);

}


private void updateLoginUi(String authenticationMessage, boolean result){
 if(result){
  context.startActivity(…)
 }
}
```

After successfully verifying the fingerprint, I launch the MainActivity,

however, on pressing the back button to go back to the fingerprint activity, I am unable to use the service. What do I need to activate or trigger in order to validate the fingerprint again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move

```
  FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler = new FingerprintHandler(this);
  fingerprintHandler.startAuthentication(fingerprintManagerCompat, null);
```

from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`.

In this case it would start authentication everytime you go into the activity, if that is what you want.